# Define label for each column value in Google Chart (Line)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization, jqplot

Sorry I don't know much about google graph api , there is what I have done

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
   data.addColumn('string', 'Day');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q1');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q2');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q3');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Q4');
    data.addRows([
    ['Day 1', 1,2,3,4,5 ],
    ['Day 2', 2,2,3,5,1 ],
    ['Day 3', 3,1,1,3,5 ],    
  ]);
```

and it generate something like this:
[image]

what I want to do is to change value on vertical bar (1,2,3,4,5) to something like (a,b,c,d,e).
please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this to your chart [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)

```
vAxis: { ticks: ['a','b','c','d','e'] }
```